# Problem connecting Wi-Fi - it says "Self-Assigned IP address"

Tags: wifi

I have a problem connecting Wi-Fi.

It says "Self-Assigned IP address" when I have renewed DHCP Lease. "No IP address" when I have not

[image]

[image]
[image]

I know this is a known issue. I have followed the general advice that I have found

1. Deleted these .plist files:

   ```
     com.apple.airport.preferences.plist
     com.apple.network.identification.plist
     NetworkInterfaces.plist
   ```
2. Renewed DHCP Lease.
3. Added new location (Clarke is the new one).
4. Turned off Wi-Fi numerous times.
5. Hard reset router a couple of times.

Notes:

It does tether with my iPhone.

Using Mojave, Mid-2012 MacBook Pro

Comment: Depending on how your WiFi router is configured, you either need to manually set the IP address, Subnet Mask and Router values to match what the WiFi router expects, or you let the WiFi router use DHCP to provide this information to your Mac.

Comment: Please use the question itself to describe the problem you want to solve, and add screenshots to make it more clear.

Comment: "Mid-2012" what?

Comment: Mid-2012 MacBook Pro

Comment: A self assigned IP address gets assigned when you don’t receive a valid DHCP response. First thing to do is set your IP manually using the addressing scheme the network uses (i.e. 192.168.1.X). Do that and see if you can ping other devices on the network.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.igeeksblog.com/internet-not-working-due-to-self-assigned-ip-address-on-mac/ suggests some steps, some of which you've tried.  In short:

1. Delete these plist files in `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/`, followed by a reboot

- `com.apple.airport.preferences.plist`
- `Networkinterface.plist`
- `preferences.plist`

2. Renew the DHCP lease on your network adapter (under Advanced -> TCP/IP)
3. Create a new Network Location in System Network Preferences
4. Reset the macOS firewall by deleting `/Macintosh HD/Library/Preferences/com.apple.alf.plist` and rebooting
5. Change the Service Order for different network adapters in System Network Preferences
6. Change the DNS servers (they suggest 1.1.1.1, 8.8.4.4, 8.8.8.8, or 9.9.9.9)